# determining orbit parameters (eccentricity, length and angle of major axis)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity

I'm trying to make an orbit simulator, and I want to draw the orbit of a satellite given its position and velocity vectors in a 2-D plane. I found [this other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72203/calculating-specific-orbital-energy-semi-major-axis-and-orbital-period-of-an-o) which tells how to calculate eccentricity and semimajor axis, but how do I figure out the orientation of the major axis (if e > 0)?

Comment: At some point you just want to either compute or look-up the closed form solution. See any upper-division or graduate mechanics text. From there it should be pretty clear how to proceed as you can find the angular dependence of the radial velocity and radial distance.

Comment: I found a couple of pdf files on orbital mechanics, the problem is that when they mention an angle, I'm not sure if it's the same angle as the one I'm talking about.

Comment: ...and I don't have a textbook. (not taking a class or anything, just fooling around with HTML5 animation and differential equation solving)

Comment: So is there a conventional term for what I'm looking for? If I knew what it was called, I could look it up.

Comment: Is it "argument of periapsis"? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_parameters

Answer (score 3):

ah, I found it -- what I really want to calculate is the [eccentricity vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_vector).

[image]

[This lecture notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-346-astrodynamics-fall-2008/lecture-notes/lec_01.pdf) also helped. I just tried implementing it in Javascript and it worked correctly on the first try! :-)

---

Here's what worked for me:

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
\vec{h} &=& \vec{r} \times \vec{v} \\ 
\mu\vec{e} &=& \vec{v} \times \vec{h} - \frac{\mu}{r}\vec{r} \\
\vec{r}_{orbit}(\theta) &=& \frac{|h|^2 \hat{u}(\theta)}{\mu + \mu\vec{e}\cdot\hat{u}(\theta) }
\end{eqnarray}$$

where $\vec{h}$ is the angular momentum, $\mu \vec{e}$ is the Laplace vector ($\mu = MG$, and $\vec{e}$ is the eccentricity vector), and $\hat{u}(\theta) = \hat{u}_x \cos \theta + \hat{u}_y \sin \theta$ is the unit vector in the orbital plane, as a function of $\theta$, which represents the angle in polar coordinates used to draw the orbit.